# Navigation bar with image centered in the middle and text on the sides of image

Tags: html, css

I try to make navigation bar with image centered in the middle and text on the sides of image in the middle, but the problem is I can not create at least a little working thing. My current code to example is below. Any suggestions how to fix ?

```css
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif; margin:0; padding: 0;}

.topBar {
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
 height: 45px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
.topBar a {
  vertical-align: middle;
 float: left;
 overflow: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 2px 16px;
 font-family: courier;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 transition: 0.6s ease;
}
.topBar a:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.topBar-logo {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
}
.topBar-textLeft {
 float: right;
}
.topBar-textRight {
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="topBar">
  <div class="topBar-textLeft">
    <a>Informacie</a>
    <a>Domov</a>
  </div>
  
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZbKfy4E.png" class="topBar-logo">
  
  <div class="topBar-textRight">
    <a>Album</a>
    <a>Kontakt</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` on the parent will create a row that is centered horizontally and vertically. You can remove all of the positioning from the children, too.

```css
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif; margin:0; padding: 0;}

.topBar {
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.topBar a {
  vertical-align: middle;
 float: left;
 overflow: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 2px 16px;
 font-family: courier;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 transition: 0.6s ease;
}
.topBar a:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="topBar">
  <div class="topBar-textLeft">
    <a>Informacie</a>
    <a>Domov</a>
  </div>
  
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZbKfy4E.png" class="topBar-logo">
  
  <div class="topBar-textRight">
    <a>Album</a>
    <a>Kontakt</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to create a div around the image and then assign 40% or some % that will cover the left and right side with the remainder going to the img div.  then get rid of the class on the img.

```css
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif; margin:0; padding: 0;}

.topBar {
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
 height: 45px;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}
.topBar a {
  vertical-align: middle;
 float: left;
 overflow: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 2px 16px;
 font-family: courier;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 transition: 0.6s ease;
}
.topBar a:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.topBar-logo {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
}
.topBar-textLeft {
 float: right;
}
.topBar-textRight {
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="topBar">
  <div class="topBar-textLeft" style='width:40%'>
    <a>Informacie</a>
    <a>Domov</a>
  </div>
  <div style='width:20%;display:inline-block;text-align:center'>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZbKfy4E.png" >
  </div>
  <div class="topBar-textRight" style='width:40%'>
    <a>Album</a>
    <a>Kontakt</a>
  </div>
</div>
```